# Ubuntu 19.04 high cpu use

Tags: gnome-shell, cpu-load, 19.04

I have high cpu use in Ubuntu 19.04, and my screen seems laggy.

Watching `top` I see gnome-shell running about 50% very often.

Comment: I'm having the same problem even when I deactivate all the extensions ... this is particularly annoying as I'm on a laptop and it makes the fans spin up all the time and reduces baterry lmife ...

Answer (score 8):

The new version of gnome-shell is not compatible with some extensions. In particular those trying to show systray, such as "TopIcons Plus" are not working well.

Disable extensions (one-by-one?) to see if this reduces CPU usage.

To do this, install the `gnome-tweaks` package.

Open tweaks, check the extensions tab on the left, and disable extensions on the right (shown below, POP_OS, but should be similar/identical in other flavors of Ubuntu):

[image: Screenshot of gnome-shell application showing disabled topicons plus extension]

An alternative to TopIcons Plus which seems to catch most of the systray devices is "KStatusNotifierItem/AppIndicator Support"

Comment: Wow!  I can toggle TopIcons on and off and watch `gnome-shell` CPU use go from ~10% of a core to 99%.

Comment: @ZachBloomquist You will notice [here](https://gitlab.com/pop-planet/TopIcons-Redux/activity) that users of 'TopIcons Redux' are in fact suffering from this bug, on Gnome shell 3.32

Comment: @ZachBloomquist It will be great if 3.32.1 has fixed the issue - the version of gnome shell in the Ubuntu repositories is still 3.32.0

Comment: @CharlesGreen you're right, it's still broken, the issue has returned after sleeping/waking the computer

Comment: Here is a comment that tells you how to temporarily patch the bug until a new GNOME version is released: https://gitlab.com/pop-planet/TopIcons-Redux/issues/12#note_166510493

Comment: @ZachBloomquist I'll give that a shot in a VM - have you tried it yet?

Comment: @CharlesGreen I have, it does seem to help somewhat - my laptop fans are no longer running at 100% all the time. `gnome-shell` still uses a decent chunk of CPU but it's not pegged to 100% all the time, which IIRC is how it was before this bug

Comment: @ZachBloomquist I ran this in my VM and it does seem to fix the problem that I encountered.  My concern is that this is basically added in as a hack, and it's up to me as the OP, to watch for changes to Gnome-Shell, and revert the fix as required.

Comment: @ZachBloomquist  Currently I'm using "KStatusNotifierItem/AppIndicator Support" for moving icons to the top - there's only one app that is giving me trouble (Liferea) and it's really not much of an issue for me.

Comment: Just checking back in, 3.32.2 does seem to fix the issue and it's available from apt.