# Brief freeze in Gnome dialogs in 19.04

Tags: gnome, 19.04, dialog

After upgrading to Ubuntu 19.04, I have noticed a visible freeze of a couple of seconds whenever I click a button of a Gnome dialog window. One case when it appears is the screen unlock window, but even the "open file" dialog in most applications gives the same behaviour.

Journalctl displays some error messages that appear to be related [EDIT: the messages were a red herring apparently; they do not appear at the same time as the bug happens.]

Any ideas as to what could be causing it? Is it a known problem? Any experiment

Comment: I have seen some errors in /home/<user>/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log too but unable to figure out if they are related to this bug or normal user logout or reboot as my system does not recover by any other means.

Comment: @AmandeepSingh Do you have the same bug that I describe above? In my case, I have checked with `tail -f /home/<user>/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log` and `journalctl -f`, and I confirm that no error messages are added to these log files when the lock-up happens.

Comment: Please check this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135671/upgraded-to-19-04-system-freezing-when-opening-activities-menu

Comment: @AmandeepSingh Thanks for the suggestion! I have disabled all extensions apart from Desktop Icons (which I believe is installed by default in Ubuntu) and the problem persists, but I'll be sure to make more testing in this direction.

Comment: My Issue got resolved after deleting CPU Power & Workspace grid extensions.

Comment: Same happens on my system and it started after updating to 19.04 from 18.10. My system uses an amd graphics card and the experimental amdgpu driver, so I should probably test with the default radeon driver. Also I have installed this system in 2012 and only upgraded to newer versions since then without reinstalling, so maybe that's an issue. Let me know if you find a cause for this. Edit: Just noticed it doesn't happen when using a new user account. So probably something related to my home directory.

Comment: @w-flo No solution yet, but the problem seems to get worse the longer Gnome runs, so for now my workaround is restarting Gnome (alt+F2-r-enter) every now and then.

Comment: Go fishing too. Enough ram?  You know program htop?

Comment: @nobody 20G is enough, I assume. ;) `htop` only tells me that the culprit is `gnome-shell` with high CPU usage.

Comment: disable  gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons  I believe it is named so. Make sure no Icons are shown on Desktop.  Any difference between wayland or X11 session?

Comment: @nobody I have tried disabling it, but it kept coming back on "on" for mysterious reasons. In the end I uninstalled it completely, and this seems to fix the problem. Yay! Thanks for the suggestion. :) Do you know if there is any workaround to get the icons back without the lag?

Comment: No, found only https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons/+bug/1815550 and thought this could be the Problem.

Comment: @nobody I googled around a bit and found that running `nemo-desktop` gets the icons back (although slightly different looking). It's best to add it to startup applications so it's always running. BTW, if you want to write an answer you deserve my +25. :) Thanks again.

Comment: Pinging also @w-flo for the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I turned out, that the freezes are a product of a bug in [gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons/+bug/1815550) is.

@Federico Poloni found his own workaround.

Go fishing is a good thing :D

Comment: I'm also having this issue and I actually tried just last week to disable the Desktop Icons extension (by logging in to the vanilla Gnome session), and the issue still occurs.

Comment: Then you have another Problem as @Federico Poloni  please make your own thread and mention that this solution is not working in your case.

Comment: Thank you for the ping Federico and thanks nobody for that pointer, removing that package from my system solved my issues! At least it looks that way right now after a fresh boot. Who needs desktop icons anyway? Will re-install before upgrading to 19.10 to hopefully see it fixed then.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use an Nvidia Optimus with modeset enabled? In my case setting `modeset=1` for `nvidia_drm` module causes intermittent freezes. You can try disabling it.

Comment: No, I have an Intel i915 and no particular kernel boot parameters. Thanks for the attempt though!

Comment: I have the exact same issue. and same graphic card.