# Upgraded from 18.04 to 19.10, but "Activities" hangs system

Tags: upgrade

I upgraded to 19.10 but whenever I press the Super key or "Activities" button on the
screen-top, the system becomes unusable. I can switch windows, but cannot do any work
on, or close any application.

I saw this thread: 
[Upgraded to 19.04 - System Freezing when Opening Activities Menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135671/upgraded-to-19-04-system-freezing-when-opening-activities-menu)

but I am not sure how to remove the workspace grid which was given as the solution. Can someone suggest:

```
    1. If removing the workspace grid will solve the problem, or is there
       something else I need to run.
    2. How to remove the workspace grid.
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely disabling gnome extensions stopped the problem for me (not just disabling every extension; the extensions feature itself had to be switched off).

```
$ gnome-tweaks
Click "Extensions" in left sidebar
Turn the switch at the top right OFF
Log out & log in again (or reboot)
```

BTW, `Alt-F2, restart` can get out of the freeze once or twice.

**Update 3/30/2020:** There is something wrong with the remnants of old extensions, even if all extensions are disabled!  Probably some gnome-shell bug or version-incompatibility corrupted things (just a guess).   Anyway, I completely fixed the problem by doing

```
rm -rf $HOME/.local/share/gnome-shell
```

while logged non-graphically on a vt (log out and wait for the login screen, then `Ctl-Alt-F5` for a vt; `Ctl-Alt-F1` to return to graphical login)

(I also removed *.local/share/gnome-settings-daemon/* and *session_migration-ubuntu* but don't really know if that was necessary -- it's probably best to just remove .*local/share/gnome-shell* at first.)

Then log in graphically, re-enable gnome extensions using `gnome-tweaks`, and check if the problem is gone.  If so, re-install any non-stock extensions from https://extensions.gnome.org/

P.S. FWIW, the "**Dash to Dock**" extension seemed to provoke problems, so I did not want to re-install it;, I tried "**Workspaces thumbnails**" instead and am happy with it.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked perfectly! Couldn't be more relieved, thanks!!!