# Ubuntu 19.10 very slow on my laptop

Tags: gnome, 19.10

I have been using Ubuntu since almost 1.5 year now, but it has always been lagging around almost all the time. I started off with Ubuntu 18.04, which made my system slow. The performance I felt was better on Windows rather then Ubuntu. But the features on Ubuntu for development purposes are definitely better than Windows, which is why I am asking for help.

Currently I am running Ubuntu 19.10. I have a Lenovo Ideapad 330 laptop, with 1TB ROM and 12 Gigs of RAM. After reading many many articles online, I even changed my swap size to 14GBs, but still no benefit

[image: System Specs]

And even when my system is idle, my CPU is in high usage

[image: System Performance]

Below is the ouput when I run the *top* command.

[image: Running processes]

Is there any way I could make it faster actually ?

Comment: What "slow" means in this case? Give us some examples. How long you are waiting when you want to open a browser or file explorer?

Comment: Is this supposed to be the output of top without running anything?

Comment: when I open chrome or any other dev tools like Android Studio, VSCode, it usually take around a minute to properly use and be usable. Not just this, but it also lags and hangs frames as I use it

Comment: @bruni yes, this is the output with just chrome running, and also the system monitor.

Comment: This issue is often due to extensions. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134943/ubuntu-19-04-high-cpu-use Alternatively Try a search on this forum “Created:2019 Gnome high cpu”. There are quite a few answered questions that might help

Comment: 14G swap is excessive. Does the slowness change if you use Intel video over AMD video, or vise-versa?

Comment: @heynnema could you explain a bit more ? I haven't tried any sort of this thing before

Comment: Change your swap back down to 4G. Switch between video cards... either in your BIOS... or via a utility provided by AMD. Also show me screenshot(s) of the `Disks` app `SMART Data` window (may take 2 screenshots to view all of the smart data).